# Make array with arrays from a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Working on a e-shop, i must read from the DB the products that have productpack not null.

productpack from the DB looks like this : 0141,3122,0104,0111,3114,0106,0117 .

I'm trying to get all the DB items that have productpack set (not null), and make them into an array with arrays with those codes (0141,3122,0104,0111,3114,0106,0117).

```
function p_productpacks(){

    $productpacks = array();
    $pack = array();

    $q = mysql_query('SELECT productpack FROM products WHERE productpack <> "";');

    while($p = mysql_fetch_object($q)){

        $pack = explode(",", $p);

        $productpacks[] = $pack;

    }

    return $productpacks;

}
```

Comment: This looks like your database model isn't properly normalized. Whenever you feel the need to write your own little micro-database logic *inside* a database, something is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array otherwise, you're overwriting existing packs:

```
$pack = explode(",", $p->productpack);

$productpacks[] = $pack;
```

For more information read about [`array_push`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) and [PHP Arrays <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (and [`mysql_fetch_object`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_object)).

Comment: So what's your question then?

Comment: well ... somehow it doesn't work, i don't know why. the array is empty

Comment: well, it will not work as expected if comma is a valid character for a product pack name

Answer (score 0):

You can get all productpacks in a CSV array using:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(productpack) as productpacks
                       FROM products WHERE productpack <> '' ");
if ($result) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  $productpacks_as_CSV_string = $row['productpacks'];
}
```

That way you only need to get one row out of the database, saving lots of time.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_object returns an object and can't be used with string processing.. if you definitely want to use this, you need to do something like:

```
$pack=explode(',',$p->productpack);
$productpacks[]=$pack
```

Or, to use a good old array instead:

```
while ($p = mysql_query($q))
{
    $pack = explode(",", $p['productpack']);
    $productpacks[] = $pack;
}
```

Comment: hmmm .. this seemsmore close to what i want to do... i will test this now .